# PCL, OpenCV and flann conflict

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library

I'm using PCL 1.6, OpenCV 2.4.2 for my program (in Qt) and there is this flann (1.7.1) conflict I cannot resolve.

I have already read a lot about it on the internet, and tried most of the solutions (not using `using namespace cv`, update the latest version of OpenCV and put PCL includes before OpenCV inludes etc.), but still whenever I use PCL and OpenCV together, the flann-lib (which PCL uses) would cause problem and say e.g. for this line of code `typedef flann::Index<Dist> FLANNIndex;`

> /usr/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h:74: error: 'flann' does not name a type

Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to have found a solution, but I'm not sure it's the best one.

1. I added `#include <flann/flann.h>` to *../include/pcl-1.6/pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h*, afterwards the error mentioned above went away.
2. But then OpenCV was having trouble to find its *"flann/flann.h"*, so I changed the directory in *../include/opencv2/flann* to *flanncv* and of course I had also to do this for every .h file which includes this directory, too.

It's not a very neat solution, but it is working for now.

Comment: This solution seems not to work for everyone. Maybe some of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481208/opencv-and-pcl-conflict?lq=1) suggestions do.

Answer (score 3):

ran into the same problem.

there's one implementation of flann in opencv, and another(probably the same) in pcl.

originally, they live in separate NAMESPACES, but if you do like

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace pcl;
```

you get the conflict there.

so, skipping the `using namespace cv;` line, and instead using cv::anything in the code solved it.