# OpenCV and PCL conflict?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, point-cloud-library

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2 and Point Cloud Library 1.6.0.

My program is working fine until I add the line...

```
#include <pcl/segmentation/segment_differences.h>
```

**This causes errors when I try to compile. I get...**

```
Error   93  error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\kdtree\kdtree_flann.h  424
Error   94  error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\kdtree\kdtree_flann.h  425
Error   95  error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\kdtree\kdtree_flann.h  427
Error   96  error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\kdtree\kdtree_flann.h  514
Error   97  error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\kdtree\kdtree_flann.h  520

C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h(520): error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol
              could be 'flann'
              or       'cv::flann'
```

So it looks like the Flann files that come with OpenCV are getting a conflict with the Flann files in PCL.

Any suggestions?

### Edit

There is a similar question here
[PCL, OpenCV and flann conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918504/pcl-opencv-and-flann-conflict?rq=1)
but it's a slightly different error...

### Edit 2

so in my main.cpp file I previously had

using namespace pcl; 
using namespace cv;

I commented these two out and updated the program to use cv::Mat etc.

but I still get errors during compile when I add...

```
#include <pcl/segmentation/segment_differences.h>

C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h(520): error C2872: 'flann' : ambiguous symbol 
          could be 'flann' 
          or       'cv::flann'
```

I've just tried renaming include\opencv2\flann\ to include\opencv2\flanncv\ and updating the includes in a bunch of opencv headers to this new flanncv directory. I'm still getting the above error...

Comment: ahh. tha´s a nasty error. how did u install pcl and opencv? maybe you can compile both from source and make them point to the same installation of flann?

Comment: I've used the windows installers they both provide. I guess I could try compile them both to use the same flann files, but i'm not really sure how.

Comment: There´s a readme file with each one that shows how to compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a fix for this without having to rebuild things is to add a null namespace to it

change instances of 
flann::something
to
::flann::something

I think it's effectivly telling it to use the global namespace and not the cv namespace.

Comment: well if this works, then job well done. I learnt something today

Comment: The problem is, that OpenCV comes with its own flann and it conflicts with the flann, which PCL depends on. I also tried to rename the namespace, but for some reason it wasn't working, but editing the include paths did the trick. Nevertheless the newer PCL 1.7 avoids this problem by changing the namespace to from flann:: to ::flann::, and this is the neater solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well I´m using pcl and openCv under linux but here goes

The problem is that both librarries are including the header file flann/flann.hpp or something similar, where the namespace flann is defined.

Now I don´t know how the libraries are installed on your machine, but I´ll assume that you used an insallable version of pcl and of openCv, so each one came with its own flann library.

Usually in the CMakeLists of both libraries there´s a line to search for the flann libraries, something like: INCLUDE_LIBRARY($(flann) REQUIRED)

a solution might be to remove the two installed libraries pcl and openCv. then download and install flann from their website. then download the nightly build of openCv and pcl, compile them and they should both be able to find the same instance of flann and so the problem might be solved

**Edit:**
One more idea, maybe the problem is simply because you used in your code:

```
using namespace pcl;
using namespace cv;
```

and so you have 2 different instances from flann namespace. remove both "using namespace" and use instead in your code pcl::thepclclass, cv::theopencvclass and see if this helps

good luck

Comment: hmmm not much luck with that, have edited above with what I've tried.

Comment: I am using on linux both pcl and openCv in one project with no problems. the thing is that they both depend on the same version of flann. I´m pretty sure if you managed to install flann separately then downloaded and compiled pcl and openCv to depend on this installed version of flann, you might get the problem solved

Comment: Are the flann files that opencv and pcl use identical or are they tweaked for use with opencv or pcl? They've been working happily together until I used #include <pcl/segmentation/segment_differences.h>.

Comment: as far as I know they just use the flann library with no tweaking, but you can ask on the pcl list as the author of flann is an active member there

Comment: I had the OpenCV-PCL flann conflict problem on Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenCV 3.2 and PCL 1.7 - omitting the "using namespace cv;" and prepending cv:: everywhere worked for me. This answer is simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135264/975443

Answer (score 0):

The solution simply is to add double colon like this (`::`) before flann
Then everything will work well.

For example, it was:

```
flann::Matrix<ElementType>(new ElementType[size_*dim_], size_, dim_);
```

became:

```
::flann::Matrix<ElementType>(new ElementType[size_*dim_], size_, dim_);
```